# RxRealm.swift errors during build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

Help me please. I need to build one old ios app but I have never worked with swift or xcode. I get errors while compiling. My understanding is that this is a package issue, not a code issue. By the way, the project is working, as its version is in the AppStore. Please help me solve this problem.

```
Type 'List<Element>' does not conform to protocol 'NotificationEmitter'
Type 'AnyRealmCollection<Element>' does not conform to protocol 'NotificationEmitter'
Type 'Results<Element>' does not conform to protocol 'NotificationEmitter'
Type 'LinkingObjects<Element>' does not conform to protocol 'NotificationEmitter'
```

[image]

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Project name' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'RxRealm'
  pod 'RxAlamofire', '5.1.0'
  pod 'RxGesture'
  pod 'Action'
  pod 'lottie-ios'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'FSPagerView'
  pod 'StreamView', :git => 'https://github.com/Macostik/StreamView.git'
  pod 'Firebase', '7.1.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '7.1.0'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  # Pods for OneSpace

  target 'Project name' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Project nameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
  
  target 'Notification Extension' do
      use_frameworks!
      pod 'RxRealm'
      pod 'RxAlamofire'
  end

end
```

Pod version:

```
pod --version
1.11.3
```

I try to setup pods from this resolution [Build compile errors in RxRealm.swift after RxRealm pod update: Type 'List<Element>' does not conform to protocol 'NotificationEmitter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70676333/build-compile-errors-in-rxrealm-swift-after-rxrealm-pod-update-type-listeleme) but but getting the following errors

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and models as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The pod appears to be a quite old version; RxRealm 4.0.3, I think the current version is 5.0.x. Please remove the images and include your podfile as text. Your cocopods may be out of date as well. What's the version? `pod --version`? It should be 1.11.3 or higher.

Comment: @Jay I have updated the question. And I will be very grateful if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'One Space' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'RxRealm'
  pod 'RxAlamofire', '6.1.0'
  pod 'RxGesture'
  pod 'Action'
  pod 'lottie-ios'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'FSPagerView'
  pod 'StreamView', :git => 'https://github.com/Macostik/StreamView.git'
  pod 'Firebase', '7.1.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '7.1.0'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  # Pods for OneSpace

  target 'One SpaceTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'One SpaceUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
  
  target 'Notification Extension' do
      use_frameworks!
      pod 'RxRealm'
      pod 'RxAlamofire'
  end

end
```